# Create non aspx views (e.g. WML) with ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, wml

Using ASP.NET MVC2, how would I go about creating a WML view for a given controller action? (Or any other non-aspx view for that matter).

E.g. `http://localhost/Store/Browse` would actually return a text/vnd.wap.wml response.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml" >
<wml>
  <card id="main" title="First Card">
    <p mode="wrap">This is a sample WML page.</p>
  </card>
</wml>
```

There are other examples where this would be useful, e.g. returning a xml packet etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of these:

1. try using an aspx view - just instead of using html tags use wml
2. return a string or ContentResult with what you want to send directly.
3. define your own ViewEngine + Views / base it on an existing viewengine.

Comment: Option 1 appears to work well provided I also set the Response ContentType to text/vnd.wap.wml. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article from Scott Hanselman.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx

Shows how to dynamically return Iphone, Windows mobile (WML) views from a single controller method.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I've read this article and I am using parts of it already to select different views based on the browser capabilities but I couldn't see anything on non-aspx views.

Comment: Ok - i misunderstood. Sounds like you are looking for the WATM: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitMobile. I could be wrong though - i have never actually tried this, its from pure reading/hear-say